# ¿Como soluciono el error "Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress."?

Tags: html, wordpress, web

Hice mi pagina web basado en Wordpress, luego quise hacer respaldo de la web, y ahora cuando abro mi pagina sale este error:

> Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.

¿Qué me recomiendan hacer para solucionar este problema?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yo recibí este error porque wordpress me dijo que la versión de PHP que estaba usando el servidor no era segura y que wordpress recomendaba la version 7.4 (yo estaba usando la 7.1)

Total acualicé a la 7.3 ya que solo eso estaba disponible en el cPanel de hostgator, entonces fué cuando recibí el error, incluso regresando a la versión anterior.

En el cPanel > Software hay una opción "Multi PHP Manager" allí está la opción de seleccionar que versión de php quieres actualizar pero abajo de la lista de versiones hay una opción que dice "inherit" (heredadaa) le di esa y se arregló mi sitio web uff!

Saludos!

Answer (score 3):

Si te encuentras en un entorno Linux prueba instalando el paquete Mysql con:

```
sudo apt-get install php*-mysqli
```

Donde **php*** es tu version de PHP actual por ejemplo: `php7.0-mysqli`.
No olvides reiniciar apache o tu servidor para aplicar los cambios.

Si es Windows necesitas la `.dll` correspondiente de MySQL, puedes configurarlo en el `php.ini`

Si utilizas un hosting:

1. Ingresa a tu cPanel.
2. Localiza la sección de Software.
3. Busca la opción de “Select PHP version”
4. Elige la versión de PHP más actual posible.
5. Consulta si esta activa la extención MySQL

Comment: Fue de gran ayuda. Segui los pasos en el cpanel del hosting y pudimos resolver. Mil gracias por esta publicación. Saludos Wilmer Manrique