# ¿Como resolver el error "Parece que tu instalación de PHP no cuenta con la extensión de MySQL, necesaria para hacer funcionar WordPress."?

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

Quiero instalar woocommerce en un sitio de wordpress y cuando cambio la versión en el hosting de php a la 7.0 que es la que requiere el plugin antes mencionado me devuelve el siguiente error "Parece que tu instalación de PHP no cuenta con la extensión de MySQL, necesaria para hacer funcionar WordPress".

Answer (score 0):

La extensión **mysql_ está obsoleta desde PHP 5.5**, por lo que deberías actualizar a la versión más reciente de WordPress. Si ya la tienes, puedes probar [la respuesta de esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/136086/como-soluciono-el-error-your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql). Aunque te sugiero que contactes con el servicio de atención al cliente de tu hosting.

Comment: También puede estar relacionado con la librería PHP_mysql que puedes instalar con apt-get install php_mysql (si estás en una distribución basada en debian)